# Weird Symbols Google

Tags: fonts

So my homepage look weird I don't know why but since i start using ubuntu 10.10 the weird symbols appear any idea?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wl8df.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens to me everyonce in a while. It's google resetting language preferences to Afrikaans (at least this is what is shown, the language displayed is not Afrikaans, I don't know if it's a language at all). You should try setting it back to english in the preferences menu (2nd item in top right corner).

Comment: LOL is true is in Afrikaans wtf oh well thank you !

Comment: No matter how hard i try to change it back to English wont let me ugh!

Comment: Try switching it back to another language first, when this happened to me I could never find english in the list of languages at first.

Comment: That help now i am using Spanish so that should work for now :)

Answer (score 1):

Further to the above (I would comment if I could)... it's Cherokee. I had the same a few weeks back, as I had this junk line in my language preferences

```
[chrome://global/locale/intl.properties]
```

CHR is the ISO language code for Cherokee, and is your browser's best match. You won't find many sites that offer Cherokee, so Google is the only one serving you a Cherokee version.

At the time I think I was convinced Xmarks was the culprit. Solution, as stated above, was to delete and re-add English.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cherokee_language